# Managing common values for multiple Maven archetypes

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-archetype

I have a number of Maven archetypes, structured as follows

```
.
├── bundle
├── bundle-for-jcrinstall
├── initial-content
├── launchpad-standalone
├── launchpad-webapp
├── servlet
└── taglib
```

For these, I would like to have a single source of common values, e.g. plugin versions, so that I can change them in just one place for all modules. The changes should end up in the generated pom.xml, so I would define e.g. `bundle/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/pom.xml` containing

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${scrplugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-scr-descriptor</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>scr</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
  <!-- snip ... -->
```

And then supply the value in the `bundle/pom.xml file`, ideally inherited from a parent pom . The problem is, I have no idea how to supply this value in `bundle/pom.xml` so that it becomes available to the generate pom.xml file.

Any ideas on how to do that, or other ways of solving this problem are more than appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resource file filtering isn't on by default, so you have to turn it on.

In the pom of your parent project; add the property you want:

```
<scrplugin.version>1.14.0</scrplugin.version>
```

In the archetype pom, add a resource filtering (assuming you're using the standard Maven organization)

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.archetype</groupId>
            <artifactId>archetype-packaging</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

This will process your poms to replace any properties that you have defined; leaving any you don't as-is. This will put the property into the archetype's output jar, so it will be a set version whenever you use that archetype library when running the archetype:generate command.

Hope that helps.

-Stopp

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I was looking so hard for a way of doing this with the maven-archetype-plugin that I forgot to look into the basic Maven mechanisms.